# in java - method that check if array has number that shows only once?

Tags: java

i want to write a method that **gets an array of int**, and return true **if the array has a number that appears only once in the array**.
how can i do this in the lowest run time and space usage??

Thank you all

Comment: Is this homework? Which strategy have you imagined?

Comment: better you explain with example... What if you have array as {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5,2}

Comment: If an algorithm has O(n) run time and O(1) space complexity, and another has O(1) run time and O(n) space complexity, which one has the lowest run time and space usage?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Excellent point, I couldn't have put it better myself.

Answer (score 1):

Create a  [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), iterate the array: for each x in the array: if x is not in the map [as key], insert (x,1) to the map, else: insert (x,map.value(x)+1) to the map.

Iterate the map, and find if  there is a key with value of 1, and return true if there is, false otherwise

It is `O(n)` time complexity and `O(n)` space complexity.

pseudocode:

```
hasUnique(array):
   map <- new hashMap
   for each x in array:
       if (map.get(x) == null): map.put(x,1)
       else: map.put(x,map.get(x)+1)
   for each key in map.keySet():
       if (map.get(key) == 1) return true
   return false
```

Since it seems like homework, I leave implementing it as an excersice to the reader.

Comment: What about space complexity? It's O(n).

Comment: @aix: I editted, I misread the question at first. Luchian: it is indeed O(n) space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try to sort the array (qsort algorithm is quite fast) and then iterate over the array once and find element(s) that don't have the same left and right to it.

You can also put elements into a hash map where the key is the element and the value - number of occurences.

//Edit:
as amit said, HashSet is also an option.